# Problem in ethernet connectivity

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, ethernet, proxy

Whenever I lock my PC for sometime then after I unlock it back I still remain connected to ethernet but internet doesn't work until I restart the PC. I'm facing this problem in ubuntu 18.04.1.  Someone please help how can I solve the issue?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you share a bit more info about your setup? Can you post the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ?

Comment: `# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`  this is content of interfaces file and I don't know how to post it in the same format as it is written in interfaces file @MrShunz

Comment: `[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no`
and this is content of NetworkManager.conf